# Upgrading to 4.16 kernel (not working)

Tags: kernel

Running Mate 16.04 LTS I tried to upgrade the kernel because I swapped my crappy wifi for an Intel AC 9260 and wanted the kernel support.

After running through the steps listed on [How to Install Linux Kernel 4.16 on Ubuntu 17.10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Softpedia)](http://news.softpedia.com/news/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-16-on-ubuntu-17-10-and-ubuntu-16-04-lts-520514.shtml) I am running into:

```
$ uname -a
Linux CQF-MSI 4.13.0-38-generic #43~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 17:48:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linu
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you rebooted after installing both of the needed packages ?

Comment: yes ive rebooted

Comment: Try downloading from your browser instead of using `wget`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade/885165#885165

Answer (score 1):

### To Upgrade Ubuntu Kernal :

Check your current version of Ubuntu :

```
$ lsb_release -a
```

Check your current ke0rnel :

```
$ uname -mrs
```

Find Latest Release :

```
$ sudo apt update
$ apt-cache search linux-generic
```

Or use :

```
$ apt-cache search linux-image
```

Install latest Version :

```
$ sudo apt install linux-image-4.xx
```

Reboot :

```
 $ sudo reboot
```

Verify the updated version :

```
$ uname -mrs
```

**Alternatively you can use UKUU:**

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ukuu -y
$ ukuu –help                          # To show commands
```

Now to use UKUU :

```
$ ukuu –list
$ xhost +
$ sudo ukuu --install v4.xx.x        # x is the version number you want to install
```

Reboot and check:

```
$ reboot
$ uname -r
```

Comment: `sudo apt install linux-image-4.16.0-041600
[sudo] password for henry: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'linux-image-4.16.0-041600-generic' for regex 'linux-image-4.16.0-041600'
linux-image-4.16.0-041600-generic is already the newest version (4.16.0-041600.201804012230).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: Dont forget to reboot after the update. And check the kernel again as explained. Alternatively you can use the second method.

Comment: `henry@CQF-MSI:~$ ukuu --list  
ukuu v18.1  
Distribution: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS  
Architecture: amd64  
Running kernel: 4.13.0-38-generic  
Kernel version: 4.13.0.38.43  
Cache: /home/henry/.cache/ukuu  
Temp: /tmp/ukuu/QOQg6SEd  
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
Found installed: 4.13.0-38.43~16.04.1  
Found installed: 4.16.0-041600.201804012230  
Found installed: 4.13.0.38.57`

Comment: Try " sudo apt-get autoremove" to remove "old" kernels. Which kernel does grub shows you when you boot up ?

Comment: Autoremove has been done.  Also this:

`ukuu --list`
`v4.16                          4.16                      Installed`  
`v4.16.0-041600.201804012230    4.16.0                    Installed`  

I'll check at grub, but its weird that uname -a still reports 4.13

Comment: Should be anything else. If its says installed its installed. What does GRUB say ? Also use "  uname -mrs " to check kernel version.

Comment: GRUB says 4.13 

`henry@CQF-MSI:~$ uname -mrs       

Linux 4.13.0-38-generic x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @An0n for the help  It turns out it was my EFI bootloader (rEFInd) where I needed to select the correct kernel.

UKUU is a great tool here.